# PHP snippets styles not affect each other

Tags: html, css

> header.php:

```
<div class="div1">
<!-- Header content -->
</div>
<style>
.div1 {
    /* Styles for div1 in the header */
}
</style>
```

> footer.php:

```
<div class="div1">
<!-- Footer content -->
</div>
<style>
.div1 {
    /* Styles for div1 in the footer */
}
</style>
```

> index.php:

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

When I put PHP snippets in index.php because they have the same class name, the styles affect each other.
I want to keep the same name but without the styles affect each other.
There is any way to achieve this or the only way it to change the names?

****please I want exactly the SAME class names not .header-div1 and .footer-div1. OR .header .div1 and .footer .div1***

Comment: It's not possible, same name === same property

Comment: div1 is div1. Any rules for div1 will apply to all div1s in the page - this is entirely logical. The solution to your problem is that you put caveats on each rule - exactly as you've already suggested! - to make them specific to a region of the page, or you use completely separate classes. What you are asking for instead, is basically a request for a magic trick: you appear to want that the page should somehow automatically know which region of the page each rule should apply to _without you telling it_. This doesn't make any sense at all, if you stop to think about it for a more than a moment

Comment: Also... `I want exactly the SAME class names`...why, exactly. Even if it was possible, why would it matter? What problem would the alternative solutions give you? The whole thing seems like a complete non-issue.

Comment: Why not ditch the classes alltogether and use `<header></header>` and `<footer></footer>` instead of your `<div>`s and then style those? Much more meaningful imho. Or use inline styles instead of classes

Comment: Please do not use unrelated tags. PHP does not know anything about CSS, and any static markup (that does not use PHP after all) would work int he same way

Comment: @brombeer is only an example.

Comment: @NicoHaase there are programmers who know both, like me, from frontend and backend. Consequently, someone who deals with PHP may have faced the same issue. So if you don't have anything to offer, it's better not to bother.

Comment: @SAI `Consequently, someone who deals with PHP may have faced the same issue`...sorry but that's irrelevant, because the tags are to indicate that the question is _about_ PHP, in order to ensure that the right people can find them and try to answer them. They are not to be used just in case someone who uses PHP might also have a HTML issue in future.  Have a look at [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: So it seems I was wrong, sorry (Nico Haase). @ADyson Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

The only way to apply different styles while using the same class name is to increase the specificity with the selector. This can be done by using a selector that includes the element type or a selector that includes two classes on the element.

```css
* {
  margin-block: 1em;
}


header.div1 {
  color: firebrick;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

footer.div1 {
  color: aliceblue;
  background-color: red;
}



header .div1 {
  color: red;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

footer .div1 {
  color: antiquewhite;
  background-color: slateblue;
}



.header.div1 {
  color: slateblue;
  background-color: mintcream;
}

.footer.div1 {
  color: mintcream;
  background-color: firebrick;
}
```

```html
<header class="div1">
  Header content
</header>

<footer class="div1">
  Footer content
</footer>

<hr>

<header>
  <div class="div1">
    Header content
  </div>
</header>

<footer>
  <div class="div1">
    Footer content
  </div>
</footer>

<hr>

<div class="header div1">
  Header content
</div>

<div class="footer div1">
  Footer content
</div>
```